# Possible to get an ordered collection from a SortedMap?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, iterator

I have a `SortedMap` (a `TreeMap`, specifically), from which I extract the values.  Later, I need to get the first and last values, as they were ordered in the `SortedMap`.

`SortedMap.values()` returns a `Collection`, whose `Iterator` preserves order.  Therefore, getting the first value is as simple as `collection.iterator().next()`.  However, getting the last value is not so simple -- iterating all the way through to get to the last is very inefficient.

Is there a way around this?  For now, I'm iterating all the way to the end and storing that value, so I only have to do it once...

Comment: How about `sortedMap.get(sortedMap.lastKey())` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Java 6 or above, you can use `NavigableMap` instead of `SortedMap`, and use its `lastEntry` method.

Otherwise, you can use `SortedMap.get(SortedMap.lastKey())`.

Comment: This is helpful.  However, I'm wondering specifically if there's a way to access the first and last values without access to the underlying map?  I no longer have access to the map where I need access to the values.  Would be nice if SortedMap.values() returned a List, for example...

Comment: No, in that case there's nothing you can do.